# Entity Framework attempting to select non-existing column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 and have defined 2 POCO's to map to my database:

```
[Table("PortfolioGroups")]
public class PortfolioGroup : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    [Column("Company_Id")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PortfolioGroupItem> PortfolioGroupItems { get; set; }

    public PortfolioGroup()
    {
        PortfolioGroupItems = new Collection<PortfolioGroupItem>();
    }
}
```

And the PortfolioGroupItem:

```
[Table("PortfolioGroupItems")]
public class PortfolioGroupItem : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    [Column("PortfolioGroup_Id")]
    public int PortfolioGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PortfolioGroupId")]
    public PortfolioGroup PortfolioGroup { get; set; }

    [Column("Trademark_Id")]
    public int? TrademarkId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TrademarkId")]
    public Trademark.Trademark Trademark { get; set; }

    [Column("TrademarkRegistration_Id")]
    public int? TrademarkRegistrationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TrademarkRegistrationId")]
    public TrademarkRegistration TrademarkRegistration { get; set; }

    [Column("Domain_Id")]
    public int? DomainId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DomainId")]
    public Domains.Domain Domain { get; set; }
}
```

However - when I attempt to query the PortfolioGroups, Entity Framework for some reason attempts to query a field named "Trademark_Id" - which doesn't exist on the PortfolioGroup entity:

```
Context.PortfolioGroups.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id && i.CompanyId == companyId);
```

Throws: 
Invalid column name 'Trademark_Id'.

I've used this kind of setup other places in my application without any problems. I simply cannot find out why EF is trying to query a column that's not in my entity!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm at the end of my rope here.

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Can you post a simple, complete repro?  I don't see how the code you posted can cause the behavior you describe.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll try. It's part of a much larger project - but I'll see if I can put something together :) 
I've never seen this kind of behavior in EF before so I'm thinking that it might have something to do with my setup - but I have NO idea where to start looking :)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I succeeded in generating a small console app with a database which recreates the problem.
I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing - but if someone could point it out I would be really grateful :) 

Link to the demo solution: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/41d3a647d29117ce07385c0c4a7b3eea20181203194606/bcf3f3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've added a Navigation Property on Trademark that requires a Foreign Key on Portfolio Group:

```
public class Trademark
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PortfolioGroup> PortfolioGroups { get; set; }

    public Trademark()
    {
        PortfolioGroups = new Collection<PortfolioGroup>();
    }
}
```

EF expects PortfolioGorup to have a Trademark_ID column to store which PortfolioGroups are associated with a Trademark.

Comment: Wow thanks David. How the h... did I miss that? 
That's a bit embarrassing :) 
Thanks man - apparently I just stared myself blind. After changing PortfolioGroup to PortfolioGroupItem on the Trademark entity everything works. 

Thanks for your help man - sorry for the inconvenience :)